# Split a huge file in LINUX into multiple small files (each less than 100MB) splitting at a specific line with pattern match

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have the below source file (~10GB) and I need to split into several small files (<100MB each) and each file should have the same header record. The tricky part is I can't just split the file at any random line by using some split command. Records belonging to an agent shouldn't be split across multiple files. For simplicity I am only showing 2 agents here (there are thousands of them in the real file).

```
Inout.csv
        Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
        DWH,Agent_1234,phone1  
        NULL,NULL,phone2  
        NULL,NULL,phone3 
        DWH,Agent_5678,phone1 
        NULL,NULL,phone2 
        NULL,NULL,phone3
        DWH,Agent_9999,phone1 
        NULL,NULL,phone2 
        NULL,NULL,phone3

Output1.csv
        Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
        DWH,Agent_1234,phone1  
        NULL,NULL,phone2  
        NULL,NULL,phone3
Output2.csv
        Src,AgentNum,PhoneNum
        DWH,Agent_5678,phone1 
        NULL,NULL,phone2 
        NULL,NULL,phone3
        DWH,Agent_9999,phone1 
        NULL,NULL,phone2 
        NULL,NULL,phone3

#!/bin/bash
    #Calculate filesize in bytes
    FileSizeBytes=`du -b $FileName | cut -f1`

    #Check for the file size
    if [[ $FileSizeBytes -gt 100000000 ]]
    then
        echo "Filesize is greater than 100MB"
        NoOfLines=`wc -l < $FileName` 
        AvgLineSize=$((FileSizeBytes / NoOfLines))
        LineCountInEachFile=$((100000000 / AvgLineSize))

            #Section for splitting the files

    else
        echo "Filesize is already less than 100MB. No splitting needed"
        exit 0
    fi
```

I an new to UNIX but trying this bash script on my own and kind of stuck at splitting the files. I am not expecting somebody to give me a full script, I am looking for any simple approach/recommendation possibly using other simple alternatives like sed or such. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is perl available for you? If not, you could try awk.

Comment: For now I am restricted to use only shell script at my current project. But if you have a pearl solution I can try for sure. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rough idea of how to do it in Perl. Please modify the regular expression if it doesn't exactly match to your actual data. I only tested it on your dummy data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    
my $l=<>; chomp($l); my $header=$l;
my $agent=""; my $fh;

while ($l=<>) {    
   chomp($l);
   if ($l=~m/^\s*[^,]+,(Agent_\d+),[^,]+/) {
       $agent="$1";
       open($fh,">","${agent}.txt") or die "$!";
       print $fh $header."\n";
   }
   print $fh $l."\n";
}
```

Use it as follows:

```
./perlscript.pl < inputfile.txt
```

If you don't have perl (check for perl at /usr/bin/perl or some other such location), I will try to do a awk script. Let me know if you find problems running in the above script.

---

In response to your updated request that you only want to split the file, with each output file as less than 100MB, with no agent records split across two files, and that that header is printed in each output file, here is a rough idea of how you can accomplish that. It doesn't to a exact-cut (because you would need to calculate before you write). If you set the ***$maxfilesize*** to a value like ***95*1024*1024*** or ***99*1024*1024***, that should let you have a file that is less than 100MB (For ex., if the maximum size of a agent's records are less than 5MB, then set the ***$maxfilesize*** to ***95*1024*1024***)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w    
# Max file size, approximately in bytes
#
# For 99MB make it as 99*1024*1024
#
my $maxfilesize=95*1024*1024;    
#my $maxfilesize=400;

my $l=<>; chomp($l); my $header=$l;

my $fh;
my $filecounter=0;
my $filename="";
my $filesize=1000000000000; # big dummy size for first iteration

while ($l=<>) {
   chomp($l);    
   if ($l=~m/^\s*[^,]+,Agent_\d+,[^,]+/) {
       if ($filesize>$maxfilesize) {
          print "FileSize: $filesize\n";
          $filecounter++; $filename=sprintf("outfile_%05d",$filecounter);
          print "Opening New File: $filename\n";
          open($fh,">","${filename}.txt") or die "$!";
          print $fh $header."\n";
          $filesize=length($header);
       }
   }
   print $fh $l."\n";
   $filesize+=length($l);
   print "FileSize: $filesize\n";
}
```

If you want more precise cuts than this, I will update it buffer the data before printing.

Comment: Thank you for the pearl script! If I see it right I think the script splits the file into different files for each agent (one file for each agent). But in my requirement, each output file can have hundreds of agents as long as it is less than 100MB. I haven't tried the script yet, so sorry if I got it all wrong :)

Comment: I see. So, you just want to have the header line, few thousand lines in each output file (with size less than 100MB)?

Comment: Yes. As long as each file is <100MB and records for each agent won't overlap across files (split should happen at the end of all the records for an agent, not randomly in between). Thank you for your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Save the header

Step 2. create a variable "content" to temp-save the things the program is going to read

Step 3. start reading the next lines, in python:

```
if line.startswith("DWH"):
    if content != "":
        #if the content.len() reaches your predefined size, output_your_header + content here and reinitiate content by 'content = ""'
        #else, content.len() is still under size limit, keep adding the new agent to content by doing 'content += line'
else:
    content += line
```

Comment: Thank you @dgg32 but I am looking for a solution in UNIX Shell.